# Cannot shutdown a VM in Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: shutdown, virtualization

I am running a VM on my Ubuntu server and I want to reboot it because

as of now I do not have CLI access to VM because I need to change display settings of the VM from the virt manager to be able to use my keyboard and screen. (and for those changes to take effect i again need a reboot) As I cannot use the keyboard I am still on the login page of the VM.

Is there a way to reboot the VM from the host itself ?

Comment: Which type of virtual manager are you using?

Comment: What hold you from shuting-down the VM from the virtual manager?

Comment: virt-manager, after powering off from the virt manager, virsh list command stills shows it as running